# How to add an element from WPF Extended Tool to grid programmaticly?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I need to create a ColorPicker element in c# code, edit it and add it to grid. I know how to create ex. Label.

```
Label label1 = new Label();
grid.Children.Add(label1);
```

I tried this but didn't work:

```
ColorPicker colorPicker10= new ColorPicker();
grid.Children.Add(colorPicker10);
```

ColorPicker is in WPF Extended tool which was added through NuGet. Anybody know how to do that?
This is how it looks like, when i add it myself in xaml:

```
<xctk:ColorPicker x:Name="colorPicker1" VerticalAlignment="Top"  ShowStandardColors="False" ShowDropDownButton="False" Height="25" Width="25" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
```

Comment: How did it fail? Please provide some more information on the matter.

Comment: It didn't recognize the ColorPicker class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either use the fully qualified name:

```
Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorPicker colorPicker10 = new Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit.ColorPicker();
grid.Children.Add(colorPicker10);
```

...or add the following using directive at the top of your source code file:

```
using Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit;
```